# Solve below somewhat symmetric equations

Tags: euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations, triangles, conic-sections, solid-geometry

Solve $x,y,z$ subject to
$$x^2+y^2 - xy = 3$$
$$(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 - (y-z)(x-z) = 4$$
$$(x-z)^2+y^2 - y(x-z) = 1$$
$$x,y,z \in R^{+}$$

My attempts:

$(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 - (y-z)(x-z) - ((x-z)^2+y^2 - y(x-z)) = xz - 2yz = (x-2y)z = 3$
$x^2+y^2 - xy - ((x-z)^2+y^2 - y(x-z)) = 2xz - yz - z^2 = (2x-y-z)z = 2$

divide above, we have $\frac{2x-y-z}{x-2y} = \frac{2}{3}$, or  $3z = 4x+y$

Then the rest is easy. But I start to get interested in if there are some geometric solution. Like the comment says, they are the elliptical cylinders in the positive octant

Comment: yes, solve $x,y,z$,  $x,y,z \in R^+$ as in the quesiton body

Comment: $x,y,z$ which satisfy all three equations

Comment: @Mike Zach I think everybody had understood the question in this way.

Comment: A more precise way to bound solutions is by recognizing that all three surfaces are *elliptical cylinders* truncated to the positive octant.  Would you mind sharing what motivates the solution of this polynomial system?  There are some higher powered symbolic methods, but you may be happy with quick and accurate numerical solutions.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, interesting. This is an exercise from my cousin's math competition training. I suspect there is some fancy trick to get a precise solution but I am happy to hear your thoughts

Comment: $(1,-1,1)$ works. To search for positive, we can try $(x,y,z)  = (1,-1,1) + t (a,b,c)$  Alternatively, try $(1,2,?)$ and $(2,1,?)$  and continue

Comment: Easy to show that $3z=4x+y$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: @Mike Zach I got the following answer $\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt7},\frac{1}{\sqrt7},\sqrt7\right).$ Show your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: If all you want is the answer, look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2+-+xy+%3D+3%2C+%28x-z%29%5E2%2B%28y-z%29%5E2+-+%28y-z%29%28x-z%29+%3D+4%2C++%28x-z%29%5E2%2By%5E2+-+y%28x-z%29+%3D+1) $\qquad $

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks for your hint, I have arrived at teh solution see attached. Though I have grown more interested in a geometrical solution now

Comment: @hardmath with some hints from other commenters i have solved thsi problem in elemantry algebra. But I wonder what a geometrical solution looks like?

Answer (score 1):

We can take a quadrilateral $ABCD$, for which:

$AC\cap BD=\{E\},$ $AC=BD=z$,$ED=x$, $EC=y$, $\measuredangle AEB=60^{\circ},$$AB=2$, $BC=1$ and $CD=\sqrt3$.

Thus, we obtain your conditions:
$$x^2+y^2-xy=ED^2+EC^2-2ED\cdot EC\cos60^{\circ}=CD^2=3,$$
$$(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2-(y-z)(x-z)=(z-x)^2+(z-y)^2-(z-x)(z-y)=$$
$$=EB^2+EA^2-2EB\cdot EA\cos60^{\circ}=AB^2=4$$ and
$$(x-z)^2+y^2-y(x-z)=(z-x)^2+y^2+y(z-x)=$$
$$=EB^2+EC^2-2EB\cdot EC\cos120^{\circ}=1.$$
Now, let $BFCD$ be a parallelogram.

Thus, $$AC=z=BD=FC$$ and
$$\measuredangle ACF=\measuredangle DEC=60^{\circ},$$ which gives that $\Delta AFC$ is equilateral triangle, $BA=2$, $BF=CD=\sqrt3$ and $BC=1.$

Now, let $R$ be a rotation around $C$ by $-60^{\circ}$ and $R\left(\left\{B\right\}\right)=\left\{G\right\}$ thus, since $\Delta BGC$ is an equilateral triangle, we obtain:
$BG=1$, $FG=R(AB)=2$ and $$FG^2=2^2=(\sqrt3)^2+1^2=BF^2+BC^2,$$ which says $$\measuredangle FBG=90^{\circ},$$ $$\measuredangle FBC=\measuredangle FBC+\measuredangle GBC=90^{\circ}+60^{\circ}=150^{\circ},$$ which gives $$z^2=AC^2=FC^2=FB^2+BC^2-2FB\cdot BC\cos150^{\circ}=3+1+3=7,$$
which gives $$z=\sqrt7$$ and from here we get the answer:
$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt7},\frac{1}{\sqrt7},\sqrt7\right).$$

Comment: Clever, but it took me some time before understanding you used three times the cosine formula to three triangles explaining why you work with this quadrilateral...

Answer (score 0):

We multiply the thrid equation by four, subtract it from two, and then [substitute with equation one solved for x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5B+%28x-z%29%5E2%2B%28y-z%29%5E2+-+%28y-z%29%28x-z%29+%5D++-+4%5B++%28x-z%29%5E2%2By%5E2+-+y%28x-z%29+%5D%3D0+++%2C+x+%3D+1%2F2+%28sqrt%283%29+sqrt%284+-+y%5E2%29+%2B+y%29).

\begin{align*}
&[ (x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 - (y-z)(x-z) ]\\  
- 4&[  (x-z)^2+y^2 - y(x-z) ]=0 \\ 
,\space &x = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4 - y^2} + y}{2}\\
\\
\implies &y = \dfrac{14 - 3 \sqrt{3}}{13},
\space  z = \pm\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}

It should be easy to figure out $x$ from here.